# Save changes made to file names in folder. All 762 of them

Tags: vb.net, replace

I downloaded a pack of roms for a SNES emulator and when I went to transfer them over I received an error on the illegal file names. So I started coding a simple app that will remove the problem char from the roms title. I got that part figured out however I cannot figure out how to save the edited file names. Keep in mind there are 762 roms in the folder so manually doing this is not an option. Thanks in advance for any guidance.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ListBox1.Items.AddRange(IO.Directory.GetFiles("c:\ROMS"))
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim Index As Integer = ListBox1.SelectedIndex
        Dim Results = (From T In ListBox1.Items
                       Select System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(CStr(T), 
                           "[""]", String.Empty).Replace("[!]", "")
                      ).ToArray

        ListBox1.Items.Clear()
        ListBox1.Items.AddRange(Results)

        If Index <> -1 Then
            ListBox1.SelectedIndex = Index
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

I am using button1 to open the folder into a listbox.
Button 2 removes the unwanted [!] from the title
Button 3 would be where the save feature is.

```
                           #######    EDIT     #####
```

I figured out what the real problem was for my particular case.
I was transferring the folder of roms over to my Xbox and apparently the is a character limit not so much a restriction on chars used. Dont know the actual allowed amount of chars to  be used but for anyone who may be trying to do what I did just use my code to remove unnecessary chars in the title.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to do it in 3 steps and not 2 or even 1? It can be done in 3 steps using your current code but it's not necessary and just over complicates it...you can do it in 1 step.

Comment: No reason really just thought I could slap something together faster than manually changing them all. 3 steps was ideal compared to the alternative. guess I like to see it as it happens. Its the saving changed file names I cannot seem to figure out.

Comment: Well, if you want to see it, add another Listbox and AddRange(Results) to it. Then in Step 3, Loop thru the items in Listbox1, grab it's corresponding new file name by index in Listbox2 and call `File.Move(originalfilename, newfilename)`. If you need help with that exact code, let me know.

Comment: If you have the time I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I posted an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another Listbox to your form called Listbox2 then use this code below. Also notice in Button2 the use of `GetDirectoryName` and `GetFileName` so that you don't replace any chars in the folder name...only the filename

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ListBox1.Items.AddRange(IO.Directory.GetFiles("c:\ROMS"))
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim Index As Integer = ListBox1.SelectedIndex
        Dim Results = (From T In ListBox1.Items
                       Select IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(CStr(T)) & "\" & System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(IO.Path.GetFileName(CStr(T)), 
                           "[""]", String.Empty).Replace("[!]", "")
                      ).ToArray

        ListBox2.Items.Clear()
        ListBox2.Items.AddRange(Results)

        If Index <> -1 Then
            ListBox1.SelectedIndex = Index
            ListBox2.SelectedIndex = Index
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        For x As Integer = 0 To Me.ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
            IO.File.Move(Me.ListBox1.Items(x), Me.ListBox2.Items(x))
        Next
        MsgBox("Done!")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Your a godsend Thank you so much.